# New R-Studio version 0.98.932 deletes .md file - how to prevent?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, rstudio

after upgrading to v0.98.932, when knitting .Rmd files it produces .md, then .html, but then deletes .md. and I need to keep it to upload to GitHub. Where would the options be to keep the .md files when knitting hmtl from .Rmd?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The question is answered [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_migrating_from_v1.html). Three ways to do this:

1. use the argument `keep_md = TRUE` in `html_document()`
2. call `rmarkdown::render()` with `clean = FALSE`
3. Use `md_document` as one of your output formats

Comment: Precisely where do you put the markdown::render() with clean = FALSE ? I'd like to try it as none of the other options is working. The file appears briefly in the directory and then is gone.

Answer (score 10):

Or you can just indicate in the settings "Keep markdown source file".

This can be done by clicking on the Settings icon that is positioned next to "Knitr HTML". Then you go to Advanced - by default "Keep markdown source file" is unchecked. Just place a checkmark and you are all done!

Comment: Added `output: md_document ...` and the knit-button showed a "knit to md_document"