# generate .Rmd file to .md instead of html with hugo/blogdown

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I have a file named `example.Rmd` under post/ folder, which contains markdown text and some code chunks. I run the command

```
build_site(run_hugo = FALSE)
```

in RStudio console to tell `blogdown` to just compile `.Rmd` files to `.md`. However, I got `example.html` instead of `example.md`

Can anyone tell me how to generate `.md` instead `.html` from `.Rmd`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292909/new-r-studio-version-0-98-932-deletes-md-file-how-to-prevent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [Section 1.5](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/output-format.html) of the **blogdown** book. The short answer is to use the filename extension `.Rmarkdown` instead of `.Rmd`.