# How can I create an .md file from a .Rmd file in order to create a TOC in hugo-Apero theme?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, hugo, blogdown

I am completely new to Rmarkdown and blogdown and I am having a hard time understanding how does .markdown, .Rmarkdown, .Rmd et .md etc... files are produced and, in some ways, are different working with Rstudio.

To be more specific, I am building a website with [Hugo Apéro](https://hugo-apero-docs.netlify.app/about/) theme in Rstudio, hence with blogdown and Rmarkdown files.

I want to create a series of blogposts related to one another and with the TOC on the left side of the page just like Alison Hill did in her own blog [here](https://www.apreshill.com/blog/2020-12-how-much-hugo/)

In theory, this is not so hard and I managed to write the firsts blog posts in my own series with some math equations and everything that I wanted with some .Rmd files.

This is were it gets tricky, when I *knit* the said .Rmd files it produces **only** one .html file. I cannot find a way to produce the .md file necessary for hugo and/or blogdown (I do not really know what does what up to here) to produce the TOC of one specific blogpost. Looking at [Alison Hill's blog posts](https://www.apreshill.com/blog/2019-02-spoonful-bundles/) it corresponds to the *On this page* TOC.

I know that Rstudio v2 need some work around to produce the .html **and** .md file (see this very specific question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292909/new-r-studio-version-0-98-932-deletes-md-file-how-to-prevent)) however, none of the proposed solutions seem to work for me.

I managed to produce an .markdown file from a .Rmarkdown file which render the TOC like I want, however, .Rmarkdown files are not the best for math rendering, (see [Creating Websites with R Markdown - Ch1.5](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/output-format.html)), are not created in Rstudio etc... which does not make me want to use this format (maybe that is a mistake ?)

The absence of TOC in the final page seem related to another element : a headers link button. Still, looking at [Alison Hill's blog posts](https://www.apreshill.com/blog/2019-02-spoonful-bundles/) I notice a link button next to each headers that I do not have if I work with .Rmd file (which produce only .html file) but they appears with the .Rmarkdown file (which produce only .md file)

So I guess my question is :

1. How can I include a TOC from the .Rmd file ?
2. How can I create a .md file from .Rmd file in Rstudio ? and why none of these solutions work for me :

   - use the argument `keep_md = TRUE` in `html_document()`
   - call `rmarkdown::render()` with `clean = FALSE`
   - Use `md_document` as one of your output formats

Also, in working on my blog post I wanted to create pannelsets like in [Hugo Apero documentation](https://hugo-apero-docs.netlify.app/learn/seedling/) and it does not work with the first syntax in a .Rmd file :

```
`{{< panelset class="greetings" >}} 
{{< panel name="Hello! :wave:" >}}
  hello
{{< /panel >}}
{{< panel name="Goodbye :dash:" >}}
  goodbye
{{< /panel >}}
{{< /panelset >}}`
```

It only works with the HTML code as provided in the documentation. I guess this is not a normal behaviour.

3. Is there a way to make the simple panelset syntax work ?

For more info, here is the result of sessionInfo() :

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7       bookdown_0.24    ps_1.6.0         later_1.3.0      digest_0.6.29   
 [6] R6_2.5.1         jsonlite_1.7.2   magrittr_2.0.1   evaluate_0.14    blogdown_1.6    
[11] stringi_1.7.6    rlang_0.4.12     promises_1.2.0.1 rstudioapi_0.13  rmarkdown_2.11  
[16] tools_4.1.2      stringr_1.4.0    servr_0.24       processx_3.5.2   httpuv_1.6.3    
[21] xfun_0.29        yaml_2.2.1       fastmap_1.1.0    compiler_4.1.2   htmltools_0.5.2 
[26] knitr_1.37
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate `.md` from `.Rmd` posts, you need to set

```r
options(blogdown.method = 'markdown')
```

in your `.Rprofile`. See [Section 1.4 of the **blogdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html) for more info.

And don't forget to delete the `.html` output files.

Alternatively, use the extension `.Rmarkdown` instead of `.Rmd`, which also gives you Markdown output instead of HTML.